# I need another way to say "will be able to be used"

Tags: word-choice

The sentence is "The analyses will be able to be used to update job descriptions and to develop transitional work programs."

Comment: The analyses will be used to update job descriptions and develop transitional work programs."

Comment: Too many passives make that sentence ugly; *"It will be possible to use the analyses to ...".*

Answer (score 1):

The analyses will help to update job descriptions and to develop transitional work programs.

Updating job descriptions and developing transitional work programs will be made easier by the analyses.

The analyses will aid in updating job descriptions and developing transitional work programs.

Answer (score 1):

The analyses will be able to be used for purpose X, but human users will be able to use the analyses for that purpose. Consequently, you could rephrase the statement in this way:

> Users will be able to update job descriptions and develop transitional work programs on the basis of these analyses.

Answer (score 1):

"The analyses will be usable for updating job descriptions and developing transitional work programs."

Answer (score 0):

How about :" *The analyses can be used to update job descriptions and develop transitional work programs*"?

Comment: But if they don't exist yet, actually they can't.

Comment: @  TimLymington For someone who really regards himself engaged in a "holy duty to assist Americans and other ex-colonials in speaking (and thinking) clearly" this is a typical comment. To say about said analyses "they do not exist yet" is a glaring mathematical logic fallacy and the one who voted +1 for this "colonial master" comment must be also deluded by thinking he or she speaks and thinks better than any American or "ex-colonial" in this site!

Comment: @64soul. I am sorry you have no sense of humour. But if the analyses "will be able to be used" as opposed to being usable, they are still hypothetical. Before you accuse others of fallacies, it would be as well to be sure you understand the terms of argument.

Answer (score 0):

The analyses will facilitate the updating of job descriptions and development of transitional work programmes

Answer (score 0):

The analyses would help facilitate job description updates and development of transitional work programs.

Comment: Hi Gina, welcome to EL&U. I like your approach, but "help facilitate" is a tautology (*facilitate* is equivalent to *help*), and presumably the OP uses "will" to make the statement definitive rather than conditional (as implied by *would*). If you [edit] it to read "The analyses will facilitate...", I would happily upvote you! PS if you plan on making future contributions here (and I hope you do), I recommend reading our guidance on [answer], and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: @Chappo: I see nothing necessarily wrong with "help facilitate"—somewhat pleonastic though it may well be. The topic here is English, not writing style.

Comment: @Robusto I had to look that up - useful word! Is the question of whether one should avoid pleonasms purely a matter of style? Now *there's* a topic for a future question! :-)